# How to get an array object with expected key and values from a huge object with a recursive method in typescript

Tags: typescript, recursion, methods

I want to create a new object with a recursive method in typescript, but I dont know, how to realize it.

the expected object looks like this:

```
expectedObject = [
{key: "location", id: "3234234"}, 
{key: "contact", id: "343423423"},
{key: "information", id: "12321"}

]
```

the origin object looks like this:

```
location = {
  id: 3234234,
  contact: Array<Contact>
}

contact = {
 id: "343423423",
information: Array<Information>
}

information = {
id: "12321",
name: "userName"
}
```

so I want to write a recursive method, which can get all id and key and push into a array object.

any solutions?

Comment: What have you tried? The second snippet also isn't valid JS. Why recursion?

Comment: because some subobject has also child object